# Enabling lightContent status bar style in a VIPER project

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, statusbar, viper-architecture

In previous versions of Swift, to change the status bar style I would use 'preferredStatusBarStyle' and return .lightContent.

This method is now unavailable, I have tried every solution on SO such as:

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

However, these techniques do not work. Can someone please shed some light on this. Currently in my plist, I have 'statusBarStyle' set to 'UIStatusBarStyleLightContent'.

You're welcome to download my project here: https://github.com/benskill/Flash-Flags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 10, [preferredStatusBarStyle](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621416-preferredstatusbarstyle) is a property, not a method. So instead of overriding it with a `func` declaration, you `override` the `getter` with a `var` declaration.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
   return .lightContent
}
```